# Position div just below bottom of browser view

Tags: html, css

What's the easiest way to put a div just underneath another div that occupies the full height of the browser?

I'm trying to setup the navigation so that when an anchor link is clicked (let's say "About Us", "Contact Us", etc), it just scrolls down to that anchor's position in the page.

So, essentially, the default page occupies 100% of the screen, the About Us occupies the second 100%, and so on.

Comment: We need to know *how* its occupying 100% of the screen. Are you using relative vs. absolute positioning, etc.?

Comment: Sounds like someone needs Jquery Scroller &/or Waypoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86J2W/) first.

You basically make all the divs absolute positioned, taking up the whole screen

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Then, you can just make each div a full screen from the top with

```
#div1 {
    top:100%;
}
```

And you can use 200%, 300%, and so on for the rest

Comment: Also, be careful of scroll rates.  If you're doing like a 1 page side with scroll events, set the scroll rate so that it matches what the proportions of the window to content height are.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking for this http://jalxob.com/cool-kitten/

Here is complete list,

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/open-source-jquery-plugins-for-building-single-page-website-layouts

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/r8XqV/1/

```
display block
```

means don't put anything else on the same row.
On top of that,

```
clear:both
```

means make sure you clear both the div on the left and the div on the right. Not needed for this case, but in case you start floating divs left and right this will make sure your bottom div always stays underneath them